# Changing jQuery ajax with datatype:jsonp into pure JS ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a jQuery AJAX call that works perfectly well:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://exampleurl.com/sub/sub2/posts?api_key=ApIKeyGoEsHEre",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){
        filter(data); // Callback function
    }
});
```

However I cannot get a pure JS version of this to work, the `dataType: jsonp` is giving me trouble. My attempts are as follows

This approach gives me an error of `Unexpected token :`, adding `?callback=filter` to the end of the URL says the page is not found

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'http://exampleurl.com/sub/sub2/posts?api_key=ApIKeyGoEsHEre';
console.log(script);
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

My second approach; Gives me an error of `Unexpected token :` as well

```
function jsonp(url) {
      var head = document.head;
      var script = document.createElement("script");

      script.setAttribute("src", url);
      head.appendChild(script);
      head.removeChild(script);
}    
function jsonpCallback(data) {
     filter(JSON.stringify(data));
}    
jsonpCallback(jsonp("http://exampleurl.com/sub/sub2/posts?api_key=ApIKeyGoEsHEre"));
```

My third approach; Gives me an error of `cannot load (the url). Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://exampleurl.com/sub/sub2/posts?api_key=ApIKeyGoEsHEre", true);

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            filter(JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    }       
    xmlhttp.send();
}
loadXMLDoc();
```

[**Here is the jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/FSyT5/)

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Are you building this in jsfiddle? Possible to see the link?

Comment: Yes, I am building in the jsFiddle. I added the link in the question

Comment: @Zeaklous http://jsfiddle.net/FSyT5/1/, I will also check how you can fix it with jQuery ;)

Comment: @plalx I don't need a jQuery fix, I already have one that I provided in the question. And when I try to implement your fix on the full jsFiddle I get an error of `An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here [jsfiddle.net/FSyT5/1](http://jsfiddle.net/FSyT5/1/)

```
var script = document.createElement('script');

script.src = 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/solacingsavant.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=Srhk9qkcJO69pAoB4ltM5uIqpwUBO7kgDqDEaCD9Jo8EafWyHE&callback=filter';

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

window.filter = function filter(data) {
    console.log(data);
};
```

EDIT:

> It seems to work in your simplified version but not in the full
>   jsFiddle, I get an error of An attempt was made to reference a Node in
>   a context where it does not exist. Any idea why?

It's because you cannot do `document.body.appendChild("<div id='fromTumblr'></div>");`

You have to create your DOM elements like:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
```

EDIT2:

> it's not finding any of the object's types even though they are found
>   in the same place in the Object in the console.

Unlike jQuery's `each`, the first parameter passed to the `forEach` callback is the item, not the index. The `index` is the second param, they have inversed APIs.

Comment: It seems to work in your simplified version but not in the full jsFiddle, I get an error of `An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.` Any idea why? [jsFiddle to show](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/FSyT5/2/)

Comment: @Zeaklous Let me check.

Comment: @plalx: you might want to define `window.filter` before appending the `<script>` tag to `<head>`, just in case the JSON-P response comes back phenomenally fast.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The current JS block will always execute to the end before the code loaded by the script runs since the script is loaded asynchronously. However it might help readability and comprehension to have it before.

Comment: @plalx Again good catch on the error, but now it's saying the object's `type`s are `undefined` even though they are found in the same place in the Object in the console. Any ideas? I promise this is the last problem, haha

Comment: @plalx Ah, thank you! I had too many small errors I suppose. Thanks for the aid!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried loading the JSONP URL in a browser, and seeing if the JavaScript it returns is valid? I suspect the error may be coming from that JavaScript, rather than what you’ve written.

However, in your second approach, you shouldn’t call `jsonpCallback`yourself. The script loaded by your `jsonp` function will do that.

Your third approach won’t work because you can’t use `xmlhttp.open` for URLs on a different domain to the script (unless the different domain supports [cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing)). The whole idea of JSON-P is to add a `<script>` tag to the page pointing at a different domain to enable cross-domain requests.

#### Edit:

Ah, spotted it. I think you literally appended `?callback=filter` to the end of the URL you’re using. You want to append a `callback` *parameter* to the end of the URL (so that Tumblr returns a valid JavaScript response, as opposed to a JSON response).

As your URL already contains the `api_key` parameter, you should add `&callback=filter`to the end of the URL (note the `&` instead of the `?`).

Comment: Like I said the jQuery version works just fine, so does opening the JSONP URL in a browser. And thanks for the information on the third approach, I didn't figure it'd work when I tried it